# Aspose OCR's resource.zip add new fonts

Tags: resources, aspose

I want to add some fonts that are not set by default. Such as, I want to add 'Open sans' font to my resource so that OCR can read out from those characters. But i cannot understand the process how to add new fonts in resource folder. Resource folder contains fonts zip inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, that would not be possible at the moment. It only works with the supported fonts below. For reference, see [this](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/ocrnet/Product+Overview) and [this](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/583435/ocr-does-not-work-for-image-containing-monotype-corsiva-font.aspx) link.

1. Arial
2. Times New Roman
3. Courier New
4. Tahoma
5. Calibri
6. Verdana